# Bluetooth Speaker support with Bluez 4.101

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, speaker

I would like to know if audio streaming using external bluetooth speaker is supported with bluez 4.101.
I have tried the same using bluez 5.43 on Raspberry Pi and it works well with bluetoothctl and aplay.
However,I  could not find bluetoothctl in bluez 4.101 and on connecting with rfcomm command, I am unable to stream music even when the speaker is connected.
Finally, I need to bring in the streaming feature on OpenWRT platform, so it would be really helpful if anyone could provide any leads on this.